# can't create excel file using vb6.0 code in all windows pcs

Tags: excel, vb6

I have developed application using vb 6.0 that creates excel file to export data. I have installed that application on more than 1000 computers that run windows. It is working fine on many computers. But around one out of 50 users complaints that this export facility doesn't work.
Below is my sample code.

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim selectedrange As Excel.Range

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set objWorkSheet = objWorkBook.Worksheets(Tag)
    Set objWorkSheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet
    
    objWorkSheet.Range("A1", "P" & 1000).Font.Name = "Arial"
    objWorkSheet.Range("A1", "P" & 1000).Font.Size = 10
    
    objWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "ABCD"
    
objExcel.Visible = True
objWorkBook.Close (True)
```

If exporting to excel using VB6.0 is not working on any pc, it never worked after many try on that pc. I have tried 1) re-installing application, 2)registering msexcel35.dll file in windows/system32 folder and windows/syswow64 folder, etc.
but that never worked for me on such computers.
I want that export facility should run on all windows pcs of my application. pls guide me what to do?

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing?  An error?  No file created?  No data exported?

Comment: Please explain how it actually fails.

Comment: Try using late-bound calls i.e. `Dim objExcel As Object` and all other variables declared `As Object`